# list 3rd column of a file with spaces only

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

for listing 3rd column I am using

```
awk '{print $3}' inputfile.txt
```

and its output looks like

```
abc
xyz
lmn
pqr
```

But I need output like

```
abc xyz lmn pqr
```

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` will always append a newline (actually, it will use `ORS` value). If you want more control, you can use `printf`:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $3}'
```

This will also print an extra space character at the end, but for most use-cases this extra space is harmless.

Comment: You could add an `END` statement to "remove" the final space and put a newline instead, but while the output will look neat in any terminal or terminal-based pager (e.g. `more` or `less`), it will actually contain the space character (0x20) followed by the backspace (0x08): `awk '{printf "%s ", $3} END { printf "\b\n" }`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/((\S*)\s){3}.*/\2/;1h;1!H;$!d;x;y/\n/ /' file
```

or more easily:

```
cut -d\  -f3 file | paste -sd\
```

Answer (score 1):

Transliterate linefeeds into spaces

```
... | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `awk` [Output Record Separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html) variable.

```
awk -v ORS=' ' '{print $3}' inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding adding a space to the beginning or end of the line:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", fs, $3; fs=FS} END{print ""}' file
```